# Filter False in a list of Booleans

Tags: python, django

I've five Product objects with 3 product's availability set to True and rest False, I'm trying to set Checkout Status Button to Out of Stock even if one product has availablity set to False.

Because cart view cannot use slug, `{% if product.availability %}` is pointless, and can't use 'for loop' or it would create multiple checkout buttons, what's the way to fix this?

Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    availablity = models.BooleanField()
```

View

```
def cart(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
```

Cart template

```
{% for product in products %}
    <p>{product.name}</p>
    <p>{product.price}</p>
{% endfor %}


<!--Checkout Status Button-->
{% if product.availability %}
    <a href="#">Checkout</a>
{% else %}
    <p>Out of stock</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So if one or more products have `availability` set to `False`, you want to set `Checkout Status Button` to `Out of stock` else set it to `<a> Checkout </a>`. Right?

Comment: @moe-asal yh that's right

Comment: You should use a boolean flag, for example `available`, and pass it to the template. There are workarounds that you can do to program this behavior in the template, but they are bad design.

Comment: you should do all calculation in `view` and send only single `True/False` to template - ie. `available = all(x.availability for x in products)`

Comment: did you try to do it in `view`? How do did you try? Show it in question (not in comment). We can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do all calculation in `view` and send only single `True/False` to template.

For example

```
products = Product.objects.all()

available = all(x.availability for x in products)

context = {..., "available": available}
```

```
{% if available %}
    <a href="#">Checkout</a>
{% else %}
    <p>Out of stock</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cart(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    availibility = True
    for prod in products:
        if prod.availability = False:
           availability = False
           break
    context = { "products" :products, "availability" :availability }
```

in Html

```
if availability` True  then show `Checkout` else `Out of Stock`
```

Answer (score 0):

In your cart view, you could add a context dictionary to your `render()` call?
So basically :

- Check `products` for the availability condition and set a variable `available` to True/False
- change your render call to `render(cart_template, {'products' : products, 'available' : available})`
- change your cart template to use `{% if available %}`